# Why isn't my code storing the items in localStorage? Rest everything is fine

Tags: javascript, html

This code cannot store the added items into the localStorage.
But its running fine
When I am reloading the page, all my items vanish.
Please help.

```js
var list = [];
        var add = document.getElementById('add');
        add.addEventListener('click', function() {
            var task = document.getElementById('task').value;
            list.push(task);
            localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(list));
            var todo_str = localStorage.getItem('todo');
            var todos = JSON.parse(todo_str);
            var html = '';
            for(var i=0; i<todos.length; i++) {
                html += '<li class="collection-item">' + todos[i] + '</li>';
            }
            document.getElementById('todos').innerHTML = html;
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Todo List</title>

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input id="task"><button class="btn" id="add">Add</button>
        <ul id="todos" class="collection"></ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A General Suggestion: I find it better to use [StoreJS](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/) instead of `localStorage`

Comment: Can you tell me the issue instead of using a different technology?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since *list* is initially empty and you are saving it in *localStorage* when the *add* button is clicked all the previously added items will be overriden

```
localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(list)); // This is overriding your items from the last session
```

You could initialize list with *localStorage* instead of an empty array if you want to persist the items from the last session

```
list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo')); // This will persist your items from the last session
```

Comment: list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo')) || [];

Comment: Hey guys, m confused. Please make me understand

Comment: When you load the page, localStorage has items from the last session. Then you initialize an empty list. Now, when the add button is clicked, you add an item to the empty list, so it now has 1 item. Then, you replace the content of localStorage with the list containing 1 item. This is where you are loosing the previous session's data. What we are proposing is to initialize the list with the contents of localStorage if it exists. So now, when you add an item, it will be appended to the items from the previous session instead of overriding them.